# Let $\phi$ denote the statement "There is no proof of $\phi$". Is it possible to prove $\phi$?

Tags: logic, paradoxes

I'm assuming that this is a paradox, as any attempt to show that a proof of the statement exists would be a contradiction, but agreement that no proof exists is itself acceptance that a proof exists.

Is there anything that could be added to my reasoning here?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liar_paradox

Comment: You may be interested in Gödel's incompleteness theorem: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/G%C3%B6del's_incompleteness_theorems. In certain axiomatic systems it is possible to construct these kinds of statements ("I am not provable"). If the system is consistent there can't be a proof (because you would be proving a false statement), and is thus incomplete.

Comment: Yes, this is a paradox of natural language. The usual resolution, as Noah Schweber's answer describes, leads to very interesting mathematics, including the incompleteness theorem.  This does not diminish, however, the paradoxical aspects of natural language and the usual reasoning that we carry out with it.

Comment: Natural language has no known sound proof system (as far as I know). So this is **not** a paradox in natural language.

Comment: @Rob Arthan: natural language has no sound proof system, precisely because it has paradoxes like this and Curry's paradox which make it inconsistent.

Comment: @CarlMummert: My point is that the natural language statement "let $\phi$idenote the statement "there is no proof of $\phi$"" is meaningless rather than paradoxical.

Comment: @Rob Arthan: I had interpreted it as "There is no proof of this sentence".

Comment: @CarlMummert: sure, but "there is no proof of this sentence" is only meaningful if we have a sound proof system for natural language (which we don't)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A *proof* presupposes an *axiom system*. The statement "There is no proof of me" is too unclear to be meaningful: what *is* clear is a statement like, $\varphi_{ZFC}=$"There is no proof *from the ZFC axioms* of me" (for example).

*Actually, that statement isn't really that clear. It's clear, **if** you believe it can be expressed in the language of ZFC! See my second bullet at the end of this answer.*

Such a statement can indeed be proved - *in a stronger axiom system*. This is a key part of [Goedel's Incompleteness Theorems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/G%C3%B6del's_incompleteness_theorems): if ZFC is "reasonably nice," then ZFC can't prove $\varphi_{ZFC}$; but the theory ZFC+"ZFC is reasonably nice" *can* prove $\varphi_{ZFC}$. This shows, among other things, that:

> If ZFC is "reasonably nice," then ZFC is *incomplete*.

So even though the sentence you've described looks a lot like the Liar Paradox, it's not paradoxical, and indeed can be used to prove theorems (this is a common theme in logic: paradoxes, when studied more closely, become theorems).

---

Now let me point out some subtleties in the above.

- First off, what does "reasonably nice" mean? Well, it's not hard to show that it's enough for ZFC to be *consistent*: if ZFC were to prove $\varphi_{ZFC}=$"There is no ZFC-proof of this statement," then ZFC would know that; so ZFC would *also* prove $\neg\varphi_{ZFC}$. So why did I go vague and write "reasonably nice?" Well, the mere consistency of ZFC leaves open the possibility that it *disproves* $\varphi_{ZFC}$ but doesn't prove it - that is, it could prove "$\varphi_{ZFC}$ is provable in ZFC" but not actually prove $\varphi_{ZFC}$. So to get the "right" behavior, we need a bit more than mere consistency - [$\omega$-consistency](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%CE%A9-consistent_theory) is enough, and indeed more than we need. (Alternatively, we could replace the sentence "$\varphi_{ZFC}$" with a slightly more complicated sentence - for a theory $T$, let $\psi_T$ be the sentence "For every proof from $T$ of me, there is a shorter *disproof* from $T$ of me." Then [Rosser showed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rosser's_trick) that if ZFC is consistent, then ZFC neither proves nor disproves $\psi_T$.)
- Second, *what the heck is $\varphi_{ZFC}$ (or related)*? When we talk about proving a *statement* from some *axioms*, it's implicit that the statement in question *is expressed in the same language as* those axioms: e.g. it doesn't make sense to ask whether the [axioms for groups](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Group_(mathematics)#Definition) prove that $\pi$ is irrational. But the language of ZFC is just the language of set theory, and $\varphi_{ZFC}$ doesn't seem to be about sets - first of all, it talks about *sentences* (or rather, *proofs* - but those are just sequences of sentences), and second, it *refers to itself*. Both of those things are weird! This is actually the meat of Goedel's proof: first, he shows how the language of set theory (actually, he proved it for the language of *arithmetic*, but set theory is even more powerful than arithmetic, so my statement is true) can [talk about sentences and proofs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/G%C3%B6del_numbering), and second he shows that [self-reference can arise](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diagonal_lemma) in this context. But this is extremely non-trivial, and is really the revolutionary part of Goedel's arguments: with these facts in hand, the rest of the proof is quite easy. (In particular, there are many theories $T$ such that $\varphi_T$ is **not** expressible in the language of $T$!)
- Finally, going back to paradoxes in natural language: what if we switch from the **Liar** to the **Used Car Salesman**? By "USC" I mean the statement, "This statement is true." This is sort of the opposite of the Liar - we can't seem to prove *anything* about it! Its analogue in mathematics proper is the statement $\theta_T=$"This statement is provable in $T$", which - surprisingly - **is provable in $T$**! (Assuming $T$ is strong enough, that is.) This is [Lob's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%C3%B6b's_theorem), and is really really weird - it represents a bizarre (to me at least) symmetry breaking between truth and falsity.

Comment: I would dispute that "There is no proof from the ZFC axioms of me" is clear, since it is not obvious how to formalize "me" in the language of ZFC.  There are ways to do so, of course, but this is nontrivial and someone who asks this question probably is not aware of the subtleties here.

Comment: @EricWofsey Quite right - and I've added a bit about this (and more).

Comment: To nitpick a bit more, I would disagree that talking about sentences and proofs in ZFC is extremely non-trivial--it is pretty much as straightforward as talking about any other mathematical concepts in ZFC is.  What is extremely nontrivial is talking about sentences and proofs in something like PA.

Comment: @EricWofsey That's fair; I still think it's extremely non-trivial, or at least the *intuitive observation* that lets you do it was super counter-intuitive to me. And really it's not much harder to do it over PA - you need some clever CRT business, but that feels like a very different sort of thing, the main idea is the same.

Comment: Ah, well, my experience was the opposite--the intuitive observation that proofs are just some combinatorial object was never surprising to me, and so if you are used to the idea that you can do ordinary mathematics in ZFC then there is nothing surprising about encoding proofs in ZFC.  But on the other hand, I found it extremely surprising that you can use clever CRT business to encode finite set theory in first-order arithmetic.